Photo slightly blurry with ZEISS 24-70mm F4 lens
I have a Sony a6400, and I recently bought a Zeiss 24-70mm f/4 lens.
When I take photos at f/22, the image appears very sharp. However, when I switch to f/4, the image becomes slightly blurry. I'm in Aperture Priority mode, photographing the same object with the same lighting and distance. Is this normal?
Picture at f/22:

Picture at f/4:


That's not "slightly blurry", that's "completely and totally unusable".

Are you using autofocus?  If yes, is it blurry everywhere or is there a sharp area somewhere (a bit closer or further to where you focused on)?  I once had a lens where the autofocus didn't work properly.  It was sharp somewhere, but often not where I wanted it to.

with Manuel Focus it's perfect , tnx @luator

Then I suggest you take a look if you can calibrate the autofocus somewhere.  On newer Sigma lenses this is possible via their USB dock, maybe Zeiss has something similar.

This does not look like defocus/misfocus. It appears to be very bad optical aberrations causing doubling/misalignment.

Do you have a filter on the lens? A cheap filter can often cause this kind of issue.
Motion blur and image stabilization can also cause similar results at times, but I rather doubt those are the issue.

"with Manuel Focus it's perfect , tnx @luator – devlopp Commented Jul 29 at 14:08"
